# Number of integral solution

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find the number of integral soultions of 2x+y+z=20 where x,y,z>=0
Attempt-: It is the case of distributing indistinguishable object into distinguishable boxes so the formula is given by C(n+r-1,r) where n =number of boxes and r= object ..so here we have r=20 but i am confused in taking n ..can't be take n=4 by splitting equation into x+x+y+z=20..??

Comment: Just take $x=1$ to $10$ individually, and add up the results for  each individual case.

Comment: taking x=1 implies y+z=18 so number of solution =19 and if we take for 1<= x <= 10 number of solution will be 19+17+15...3+1=5*(1+19)=100!! but it is not the answer..!!@ астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг

Comment: Did you add the result for $x=0$? Then you should get $121$.

Comment: okk it will come 121 ...but we willnot consider the same for y=0 and then 2x+z AND z=0 ,2x+y.. ??@ астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг

Comment: Why should we again consider $y=0$? The case $y=0$ was already covered bit-by-bit separately when we put values for $x=0,1,2,...,10$. Similarly, the case $z=0$ was also covered bit-by-bit when we varied $x$. Hence, the answer should be $121$.

Comment: thank you ! got the answer !!

Comment: You've got the answer, but I am still wondering: could we have done this, if say our equation was like $74x + 38y+97z+120w=49,688$? I mean, if all of them had coefficients, then what would the formula be like?

Comment: correct...!!the number of integral solution for this equation will not be solved through this trick !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the equation has the form $kx+y+z=n$, we can use the fact that the number of solutions in non-negative integers to $y+z=m$ is $m+1$ to get an easy solution: we want

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{x=0}^{\lfloor n/k\rfloor}(n+1-kx)&=(n+1)\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}k\right\rfloor+1\right)-k\sum_{x=0}^{\lfloor n/k\rfloor}x\\
&=(n+1)\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}k\right\rfloor+1\right)-\frac{k}2\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{n}k\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}k\right\rfloor+1\right)\\
&=\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}k\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(n+1-\frac{k}2\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{n}k\right\rfloor\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$

In this case we want

$$\sum_{x=0}^{10}(21-2x)=11\cdot21-2\sum_{x=0}^{10}x=11\cdot21-10\cdot11=11^2=121\;.$$

This type is a very special case, however; with more variables and uglier coefficients the problem becomes computationally messy.

Comment: @BrianMScott That was what we were discussing above. In truth, we are at problem when there are many coefficients involved in the equation, and the computation has to unfortunately be done explicitly.